# my custom class implementing ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener is not working

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka-2.2.7-RELEASE. I'm trying to capture the event when a consumer is ready to consume message and trying to use ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener but it's not working. Please suggest.

```
@Component
public class ConsumerAwareRebalanceListenerImpl implements ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener {

  public void ConsumerAwareRebalanceListenerImpl(){
    System.out.println(" In ConsumerAwareRebalanceListenerImpl constructor");
  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    partitions.forEach( item -> {
      TestConsumerConstants.consumerEventsMap.put("key-"+item.partition(), item.partition());
    });

  }

  @Override
  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions){
    TestConsumerConstants.consumerEventsMap.put(consumer.toString(), partitions);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem and it's working now. All I had to do is, set the containerProperty 'setConsumerRebalanceListener' of the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory to my custom class instance as shown below

> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new
>   ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
>   factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(kafkaConsumerRebalanceListener);